# How do I set a new cell after the last existing column?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I need to set a new column called `Status` after the last existing column, but my code is some columns before and using getLastColumn displays nothing.
 How do I set a new cell **after the last column** ("Link especificação")?

```
 private Workbook setStatus(Workbook wb, Map<String, Integer> header, List<ValidacaoResultado> validation, Planilha planilha) {
        Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);
        CellStyle style;
        int coluna = header.size() + 1;
        List<BasicDBObject> lista = planilha.getSpec();
        Map<Integer, String> items = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, String> itemsValidacao = new HashMap<>();
        for (BasicDBObject itemsNome : lista) {
            Map extras = (Map) itemsNome.get("extras");
            items.put(Integer.parseInt(extras.get("linha").toString()) - 1, itemsNome.get("peca_nome").toString());
        }
        try {
            for (ValidacaoResultado aValidation : validation) {
                if (aValidation.getSpec() != null) {
                    if (aValidation.getArquivo() != null) {
                        String nomeOriginal = aValidation.getSpec().get("peca_nome").toString();
                        itemsValidacao.put(nomeOriginal, aValidation.getResultadoConsolidado());
                    } else {
                        String nomeOriginal = aValidation.getSpec().get("peca_nome").toString();
                        itemsValidacao.put(nomeOriginal, aValidation.getResultadoConsolidado());
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error(this, "erro");
        }

        for (Row row : sheet) {
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                if (row.getRowNum() == LINHA_CABECALHO && cell.getColumnIndex() == header.size()) {
                    style = cell.getCellStyle();
                    Cell status = row.createCell(coluna);
                    status.setCellValue("Status");
                    status.setCellStyle(style);
                }
                if (cell.getColumnIndex() == coluna && row.getRowNum() > LINHA_CABECALHO) {
                    String peca = items.get(row.getRowNum());
                    String status = itemsValidacao.get(peca);
                    if (status != null) {
                        if (status.toLowerCase().contains("spec") || status.toLowerCase().contains("media")) {
                            status = "Não contém mídia.";
                        }
                    }
                    cell.setCellValue(status);
                }
            }
        }
        return wb;
    }
```

This is the result code
[image]

This is the result when I set the new cell as `row.getLastColumn + 1`
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Cell status = row.createCell(row.getLastCellNum());
```

This should do the trick, `getLastCellNum()` already returns the last index + 1 (which equals the 1-based cell number).
After this it's necessary to adjust the cell size and visibility:

```
sheet.setColumnHidden(row.getLastCellNum(), false);
sheet.autoSizeColumn(row.getLastCellNum());
```